# Registry Monitoring using RegNotifyChangeKeyValue

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, c++17

The below code is to monitor the changes occurred in the registry (add, delete, modify) the waiting is done till some changed is occurred

Now looking for output in which key the change action is performed
the changes in registry the key name should be the output

```
void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    DWORD  dwFilter = REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_NAME |
        REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
        REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET |
        REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY| REG_NOTIFY_THREAD_AGNOSTIC;

    HANDLE hEvent;
    HKEY   hMainKey;
    HKEY   hKey;
    LONG   lErrorCode;


    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        TEXT("SOFTWARE\\444\\1"), 0, KEY_NOTIFY | KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);


    // Create an event.
    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (hEvent == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CreateEvent (%d).\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Watch the registry key for a change of value.
    lErrorCode = RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(hKey,
        TRUE,
        dwFilter,
        hEvent,
        TRUE);
    if (lErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Error in RegNotifyChangeKeyValue (%d).\n"), lErrorCode);
        return;
    }

    // Wait for an event to occur.
    _tprintf(TEXT("Waiting for a change in the specified key...\n"));
    if (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Error in WaitForSingleObject (%d).\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Get chile events for the event key ... In this case select. Display the key name and values.

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nChange has occurred.\n"));

        std::cout << hEvent << std::endl;
        _tprintf(TEXT("the modified key is",hEvent));//this was commited

        Sleep(2000);
        return;

    }

    // Close the key.
    lErrorCode = RegCloseKey(hKey);
    if (lErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Error in RegCloseKey (%d).\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Close the handle.
    if (!CloseHandle(hEvent))
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CloseHandle.\n"));
        return;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: i want to print the key in which the change has occurred . Is it possible to print this?

Comment: You will have to search for it. (After all, there may be multiple changes.)